# WPF - insufficient memory when doing copy/paste vs drag/drop with view model data

Tags: wpf, mvvm, drag-and-drop, treeview, copy-paste

I have a `TreeView` that provides drag and drop as well as copy/paste functionality.  I extended `TreeViewItem` to provide that functionality.

The **drag and drop** works fine.  The tree is bound to a view model, and the drag is initiated in the `TreeViewItem` custom class such as:

```
    protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // ...
        if (canDrag)
        {
            DragDrop.DoDragDrop(this, DataContext, DragDropEffects.Copy);
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

The drop is initiated such as:

```
    protected override void OnDrop(DragEventArgs e)
    {
        // ...
        Paste(e.Data);
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

which calls a paste method that takes in an `IDataObject` such as:

```
    protected void Paste(IDataObject data)
    {
        // ...
        if (data.GetDataPresent(typeof(FooViewModel)) == true)
        {
            // process Foo drop
            copiedFoo = data.GetData(typeof(FooViewModel)) as FooViewModel;
            // ...
        }
    }
```

The **copy/paste** operation is set up as follows.  The copy is initiated in the `TreeViewItem` custom class such as:

```
    void CopyExecuted(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Clipboard.Clear();
        Clipboard.SetData(DataContext.GetType().ToString(), DataContext);
    }
```

The paste is initiated such as:

```
    void PasteExecuted(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Paste(Clipboard.GetDataObject());
    }
```

calling the same paste method with `IDataObject` above.

**Issue:** The same paste method fails at the `GetData()` call with an *Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program* message when called from a copy/paste operation.  I've even passed in an empty view model instance to the clipboard, with the same insufficient memory result.

There has been a known VS2010 issue similar to this, explained [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/27/patch-for-cut-copy-insufficient-memory-issue-with-vs-2010.aspx).  I installed that hotfix, but the memory issue still persists.

Any ideas?  Should I be interacting with the `Clipboard` differently?  Thanks!

Comment: The VS2010 issue you address was an issue with the VS2010 application itself. This is something else...Should you really be putting that kind of object into the clipboard?

Comment: @Paul, thanks.  The view models have a small enough footprint that putting them into a DataObject for drag/drop doesn't seem to be an issue.  Is the clipboard handling of the DataObject more memory intensive?

Comment: I had this issue in the past and I honestly can't remember how I resolved it. I believe it had to do with storing an Object in memory, and I think I ended up serializing the object, but I'm not positive.

Comment: @Rachel, thanks.  I was thinking about resorting to serializing the view model and getting text from the Clipboard if there isn't an easier way.

Comment: The Clipboard means COM.  Is your ViewModel and its assembly `ComVisible(true)`?  It should also be serializable or can be copied by value, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @Will, thanks.  The ViewModel assembly was not com visible, nor serializable.  I'll retry when both are true.

Comment: @DaveClemmer: Its a wild stab in the dark, but sometimes you miss the cat.

Comment: Still have memory issue with ComVisible == true and serializable objects, will go with Rachel's approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this issue in the past, and it has to do with storing an object in the ClipBoard. I can't remember exactly why, but I needed to serialize my object and store the `byte[]` in the clipboard instead of the object itself.

The code I used looked something like this:

Writing:

```
byte[] data = SerializationHelpers.SerializeToBinary<TreeNodeBase>(
    selectedTreeNode, 
    new Type[] { typeof(TreeNodeA), typeof(TreeNodeB),typeof(TreeNodeC)}
);

Clipboard.SetDataObject(data, true);
```

Reading:

```
IDataObject data = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
if (data.GetDataPresent(typeof(byte[])))
{
    MyClass obj = SerializationHelpers.DeserializeFromBinary<TreeNodeBase>(
        (byte[])data.GetData(typeof(byte[])), 
        new Type[] {typeof(TreeNodeA), typeof(TreeNodeB),typeof(TreeNodeC)}
    );
}
```

Serialization Classes

```
public static byte[] SerializeToBinary<T>(T obj, Type[] extraTypes)
{
    if (obj == null)
        return null;

    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        DataContractSerializer dcs = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T), extraTypes);
        dcs.WriteObject(ms, obj);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}

public static T DeserializeFromBinary<T>(byte[] data, Type[] extraTypes)
{
    if (data.Length == 0)
        return default(T);

    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        ms.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        ms.Seek(0, 0);

        DataContractSerializer dcs = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T), extraTypes);
        return (T)dcs.ReadObject(ms);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 thanks for presenting a serialization approach, which I may take.  One little hitch with this approach is that I'll need to pass the data type to the Clipboard as well, since different tree nodes are of different types, perhaps pass that along as Clipboard text?

Comment: Do your TreeNodes inherit from the same Base Type? If so, you can simply cast the object as the BaseType. Providing you include any sub types of the base type when serializing/deserializing, it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Yes, I do have a common base type, and can pass a long list of the subtypes.  My main problem right now is that (unlike my model classes), my view model classes weren't designed to be serializable, so a bit of rework to do!