# Clipboard + PresentationFramework = OutOfMemoryException?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, clipboard

Why does `System.Windows.Clipboard`(PresentationCore.dll) is not friendly with the 
`System.Windows.Thickness` (PresentationFramework.dll) but friendly with `System.Windows.Point` (WindowsBase.dll)

```
using System;
namespace ConsoleApplication5 {
    class Program {
        /*
        * Add references to 
        * WindowsBase.dll (Point)
        * PresentationFramework.dll (Thickness)
        * PresentationCore.dll (Clipboard)
        */

        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Test myTest = new Test();
            System.Windows.Clipboard.SetData("myformat", myTest);
            // OutOfMemoryException
            Object myPastedTest = System.Windows.Clipboard.GetData("myformat");
        }
    }

    [Serializable]
    class Test
    {
        // COMMENT THE LINES BELLOW PresentationFramework TO WORK OK!
        // PresentationFramework.dll
        //public System.Windows.Thickness MyThickness { get; set; } 
        public System.Windows.Media.Brush MyBrush { get; set; }

        // WindowsBase.dll
        public System.Windows.Point MyPoint { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Comment: How much data is on the clipboard?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7000676/302677) may provide you with a solution, but I can't tell you why the Clipboard hates certain objects and not others. I think its related to if the object is serializable or not

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Brush class isn't serializable and causes the OutOfMemoryException to be thrown (see http://www.grumpydev.com/2009/09/05/system-outofmemoryexception-gotcha-using-clipboard-getdata-in-wpf/).  You might be able to serialize the Test class to XAML and put that onto the clipboard instead, see this link for info:

[How can i serialize xaml "Brush"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488476/how-can-i-serialize-xaml-brush)

Answer (score 1):

According to msdn, [`Point`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.point.aspx) has `SerializableAttribute`, while [`Thickness`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.thickness.aspx) does not. The `SerializableAttribute` doesn't get applied to the class members. This explains why `Clipboard.SetData()` fails silently, and why `Clipboard.GetData()` returns garbage.

You can write a wrapper around `Thickness` that implements `ISerializable` and has `SerializableAttribute`, like this:

```
[Serializable]
public struct SerializableThickness : ISerializable
{
    public Thickness Data;

    public SerializableThickness(Thickness t)
    {
        Data = t;
    }

    #region ISerializable
    private const string LeftField = "LeftField";
    private const string TopField = "TopField";
    private const string RightField = "RightField";
    private const string BottomField = "BottomField";

    private SerializableThickness(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        if (info == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("info");

        var enumerator = info.GetEnumerator();
        bool[] found = { false, false, false, false };
        double[] values = new double[4];
        while (enumerator.MoveNext() && !found.All(x => x))
        {
            switch (enumerator.Name)
            {
                case LeftField:
                    found[0] = true;
                    values[0] = (double)enumerator.Value;
                break;

                case TopField:
                    found[1] = true;
                    values[1] = (double)enumerator.Value;
                break;

                case RightField:
                    found[2] = true;
                    values[2] = (double)enumerator.Value;
                break;

                case BottomField:
                    found[3] = true;
                    values[3] = (double)enumerator.Value;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!found.All(x => x))
            throw new SerializationException("Missing serializable members");

        Data = new Thickness(values[0], values[1], values[2], values[3]);
    }

    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        info.AddValue(LeftField, Data.Left);
        info.AddValue(TopField, Data.Top);
        info.AddValue(RightField, Data.Right);
        info.AddValue(BottomField, Data.Bottom);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: what to do to serialize a Thickness?

Comment: @serhio, write a wrapper class that has `SerializableAttribute`.

Comment: @serhio, I've added a sample wrapper.

Comment: So, is it your idea to duplicate all structures from the System.Windows. namespace? Brush? other ones?...

Comment: @serhio, you are wrong. Some structures are already serializable: `Size`, `Point`, many others. `Clipboard` works on serializable data only: `An object must be serializable for it to be put on the Clipboard. To make a type serializable, mark it with the SerializableAttribute attribute. If you pass a non-serializable object to a Clipboard method, the method will fail without throwing an exception.`(quote from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/637ys738.aspx). There's no other way except making your data serializable.